# Prisma one to many self relation

Tags: typescript, prisma

I'm looking at the Prisma docs and trying to create a one-to-many self relation as in the model below:

```
model Shoe {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
  sku         String   @unique
  model       String   @db.VarChar(50)
  description String   @db.VarChar(256)
  image       String   @db.VarChar(256)
  category    String   @db.VarChar(256)
  gender      Gender
  size        String
  stock       Int
  variants    Shoe[]   @relation("variants")
}

enum Gender {
  Men
  Women
}
```

As I understand from reading the docs this should work as they have a very similar example, however, I get the error below:

```
Error: Prisma schema validation - (get-dmmf wasm)
Error code: P1012
error: Error validating field `variants` in model `Shoe`: The relation field `variants` on model `Shoe` is missing an opposite relation field on the model `Shoe`. Either run `prisma format` or add it manually.
```

I need to have a model with a main sku and any variants of it, e.g. different size, need to be connected to it.

Comment: Are you sure this is how you would model this relationship in a relational database?

Comment: Actually no, I think creating a ShoeVariant model with properties to hold the data that can vary is a better approach but I'm still unsure why prisma is throwing that error since it's almost a carbon copy of their docs from what I can tell.

Comment: That sounds more like it. When you have resolved your own problem, feel free to post an answer to your own question (be detailed!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a ShoeVariant model to hold the data that can change only.

```
model Shoe {
  id          Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt   DateTime      @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime      @updatedAt
  sku         String        @unique
  model       String        @db.VarChar(50)
  description String        @db.VarChar(256)
  image       String        @db.VarChar(256)
  category    String        @db.VarChar(256)
  gender      Gender
  size        String
  stock       Int
  variants    ShoeVariant[]
}

model ShoeVariant {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  sku       String   @unique
  size      String
  stock     Int
  Shoe      Shoe     @relation(fields: [shoeId], references: [id])
  shoeId    Int
}

enum Gender {
  Men
  Women
}
```

I'd say this is a better approach since it does not hold duplicated data.